# find nth word of a fibonacci word sequence (Java)

Tags: java, sequence, fibonacci

I'm trying to solve this assignment:

Let x[0] =0; x[1] =1; x[i] = x[i-2] + x[i-1]

Find the kth char of the word x[n] to see if it's '0' or '1', with bound of 1 <= k < n <= 93

For example, with the sequence 0110110101101 we have

x[0] = 0

x[1] = 1

x[2] = 01

x[3] = 101

x[4] = 01101

x[5] = 10101101

When I test with n = 44 and higher, the IDE throws a OutOfMemoryError java heap space. I understand that the way I'm doing would store the nth word, the n-1th word, and the n-2th word of the sequence and that would occupy a lot of memory but I can't figure out a better way.

After some draft work on papers I also see that to find the nth word after n = 3, the while loop only need to run n-2 times  but no luck implementing

I also tried to store each word in a String ArrayList and do it with recursive but it's even less efficient

Any tip is appreciated

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BinarySequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = read.nextInt(); //number of test to run
        while (t>0){
            String s0 = "0";
            String s1 = "1";
            int n = read.nextInt(); //nth fibonacci word
            int k = read.nextInt(); // kth char of the word
            System.out.println(fib(s0,s1,n-1).charAt(k-1));
            t--;
        }
    }
    private static String fib(String s0,String s1, int n) {
        String ans ="";
        if(n==0)
            return s0;
        else if(n==1)
            return s1;
        else {
            while(n>=0){
                ans = s0+s1;
                s0=s1;
                s1=ans;
                n--;
            }
            return ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `k` is at most 93, once a word is longer than 93 characters you don't need to keep expanding it, because those will stay as the first 93 characters.

Comment: @kaya3 Sorry, i don't quite understand, can you please elaborate ? 
n is bounded at 93 and k is bounded to be smaller than n so a word x[i] can't get bigger than 93 characters, if that's what you meant.

Comment: No, the words get **much** longer than 93 characters - their length grows exponentially, like the Fibonacci sequence, that is why you are getting `OutOfMemoryError`. What I'm saying is you don't need to compute words that are longer than 93 characters, since every word longer than 93 characters has the same first 93 characters.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't think this is quite true - notice that the first character alternates with every successive `x`. There is definitely a similar optimisation that can be done though. Maybe computing the first 93-long word and the one after it would be sufficient, with an `n%2==0` check.

Comment: @Oli Ah, good point - yes, you need two words longer than 93 characters, not one, and then they alternate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input `k` is limited to be between `1` and `92`, so for calculating the sequence string you only need the first 92 characters. However, the start of the string is changing for each different `x[i]` value. For the first eleven¹ `x[i]` values the string depends on the full value of `x[i-1]` and `x[i-2]`, but after/at the eleventh `x[i]` value the first string of `x[i-2]` is already long enough that the value of `x[i-1]` doesn't matter anymore, as it is concatenated at the end of the result. The value of `x[i-1]` and `x[i-2]` for bigger indices can be shown as this:

```
x[i-1] = 1111111...1111111 + xxxxxxxxxx
x[i-2] = 2222222...2222222 + yyyyyyyyyy
x[i] = 2222222...2222222 + yyyyyyyyyy + 1111111...1111111 + xxxxxxxxxx
```

Assume that the `111...111`/`222...222` parts (these are not the actual characters of course) are 92 characters long, then you don't need the remaining stuff `xxxxx...` and `yyyyy...` after that anymore, as you cannot reach them with the limited `k` value anyway. So for your problem, the sequence of

```
x[i] = 2222222...2222222 + yyyyyyyyyy + 1111111...1111111 + xxxxxxxxxx
```

is the same as

```
x[i] = 2222222...2222222
```

for high enough `i`.

The remaining problem is now to calculate/select which sequence of `111..111` or `222...222` should be used when you calculate something like `x[24]` or even `x[80]`. Most likely it is something like an odd/even check where you write something like: "When `n` is even, use `x[10]`, otherwise use `x[11]`.".

*¹) Check for any off-by-one errors, the threshold of 92 characters might not be at index `11`.*

Comment: You can edit the answer that you deleted and then un-delete it. Is there a reason why you didn't do that? When you edit, you can remove the entire answer and write a new one from scratch.

Comment: @Abra My first approach was different (and wrong). I do not want to edit an answer which uses one approach to a completely different approach, might look weird in the history of the answer. So I separated these approaches/answers.

Comment: I see, I ran a fibonacci calculation with F(0) = 1 and F(1) = 1 (because x[0] and x[1] each has 1 character) to calculate the number of characters and I see that at F(13), which is x[13], is the sum of F(11) and F(12). In which F(11) = 144 and F(12) = 233, which means x[11] has 144 characters and x[12] has 233 characters.

So to be sure, any  n higher than 13 would need a check to see if it repeated the x[11] or the x[12] word, is that correct ?

Comment: @LongDoan That's correct. The characters after the 92th character aren't relevant anymore, not to mentioned the value of `x[i-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that works for any `k` that is an `int` and contains no expensive concatenation operations, with `O(1)` memory and `O(log(k))` time<sup>1</sup>.

## Prefixes and Parity

This algorithm uses the observation that @Progman made in their answer, that if `a < b` and `a` and `b` have the same [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)), then `x[a]` is a prefix of `x[b]` (this follows by induction from the fact that `x[n-2]` is a prefix of `x[n]`). This means that the we don't need to calculate `n` items in the sequence, we only need to find `j`, which I define as the smallest number such that the length of `x[j]` is greater than `k`, and `j` has the same parity as `n`.

For example, if `n = 12345` and `k = 1`, then we only need to calculate up to `x[3] = 101` because we know that `x[3]` is a prefix of `x[12345]` as `3` and `12345` are both odd. So the answer is `0`.

## Getting down to `O(1)` memory

The method used to avoid storing long sequences of zeros and ones is as follows:

### No need to calculate `x`

First note that the length of the word `x[n]` is equal to `fib[n]` where `fib` is the Fibonacci sequence. So, rather than calculate the strings in `x` and indexing into `x[n]` to find whether to return `1` or `0`, the method uses the fact that `x[n] = x[n-2] + x[n-1]`. You can work out whether `x[n][k]` is part of `x[n-2]` or `x[n-1]` by comparing `k` to the length of `x[n-2]` (where the length of `x[n-2]` is `fib[n-2]`). After this comparison, it is known whether `x[n][k]` is equal to `x[n-2][k]` or `x[n-1][k-fib[n-2]]`. We then repeat this process with `n` set to `n-1` or `n-2` as appropriate, and `k` left as unchanged or set to `k-fib[n-2]` as appropriate. This is repeated until `n == 0` or `n == 1`, at which point `k` will be `0`, so `x[n][k]` either equals `x[0][0] = 0` or `x[1][0] = 1`, by definition.

### No need to store `fib`

`x` is not needed in the calculation, only `fib`, which avoids storing the long sequences of numbers, however surely we need to store all Fibonacci numbers up to `fib[j]` in order to do the step defined in the previous paragraph? No, we do not! This is because we first find `j`, only keeping `fib[i-1]` and `fib[i]` in memory. We then rearrange the equation to find `fib[n-2] = fib[n] - fib[n-1]`, and use this to backtrack down the Fibonacci sequence to find `x[n][k]`.

## Implementation

Now that I've explained the algorithm, here's a Java implementation:

First we define a `Fib` class to encapsulate the Fibonacci sequence, keeping the code neater. (You could move this to an inner class if you need to stick to one file.)

```java
class Fib {
    private long a = 0;
    private long b = 1;
    private int index = 0;

    void advance() {
        long sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
        index++;
    }

    void backtrack() {
        long diff = b - a;
        b = a;
        a = diff;
        index--;
    }

    long getPreviousValue() {
        return a;
    }

    long getCurrentValue() {
        return b;
    }

    int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Then, the actual algorithm:

```java
public class Main {
    public static int fibNK(int n, int k) {
        Fib fib = new Fib();
        // if n is odd, go to the next fib so that fib.getIndex() is 1
        // this ensures that n and fib.getIndex() are either both even or both odd
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            fib.advance();
        }
        // find the first fibonacci number greater than k that is still even/odd
        while (k >= fib.getCurrentValue()) {
            // x+2 is even if x is even, so advance twice
            fib.advance();
            fib.advance();
        }
        // now to find character k of the word:

        // if we're looking at the first or second fibonacci word, "0" or "1",
        // then the character at index k must be 0 or 1
        while (fib.getIndex() > 1) {
            // only fib[i] and fib[i-1] are stored, but fib[i-2] is needed, so backtrack
            fib.backtrack();
            // we are trying to find fibWord[i][k]
            // fibWord[i][k] = fibWord[i-2] + fibWord[i-1]
            // if k >= fibWord[i-2].length, then the target character is in the second part of the word, fibWord[i-1]
            if (k >= fib.getPreviousValue()) {
                // specifically, if k >= fib[i-2], then fibWord[i][k]==fibWord[i-1][k-fibWord[i-2].length]
                k -= fib.getPreviousValue();
            } else {
                // otherwise, fibWord[i][k]==fibWord[i-2][k], so another backtrack is needed
                fib.backtrack();
            }
        }
        // return either 0 or 1
        return fib.getIndex();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test the algorithm by using to print the first few words in `x`, one letter at a time
        Fib fib = new Fib();

        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < fib.getCurrentValue(); k++) {
                System.out.print(fibNK(n, k));
            }
            System.out.println();
            fib.advance();
        }
    }
}
```

## Go `BigInteger` or go home

The `O(log(k))` time complexity means that this runs very fast, even for very large `k` values. If you want values of `k` larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is equivalent to values of `n` greater than `45`) you could change `k` to a `long` but this may cause overflow errors when calculating Fibonacci numbers, so you will need to change some of the variables to [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)s, though this will slightly increase the time and space complexity.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Fibonacci sequence has an [exponential lower bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571433/exponential-lower-bound-for-fibonacci-numbers), so the length of `x[n]` is greater than `(3/2)**n`, meaning that `O(log(k))` Fibonacci numbers need to be calculated to find one greater than `k`. The second phase then does the same number of "backtrack" operations to get back to `x[0]` or `x[1]`, which is an extra `O(log(k))` time, resulting in `O(log(k))` in total.

Comment: Many thanks, but there is this, at the declaration of long a, shouldn't it be 1 instead of 0? Because x[0] =0 and x[1] =1, essentially means both x[0] and x[1] has 1 char, and by setting first element at 1, it would offset the result of each element (here is the length of the word) a lot in contrast to setting the first to 0. Or did you set it to 0 because it does not affect the result/ is accounted for in your implementation ?

I edited because at first I thought it would offset the whole sequence by only 1 element, turns out, it's not

Comment: @LongDoan `long a = 0` in `Fib` is correct, since `getCurrentValue` returns `b`. So calling `getCurrentValue` on a newly-created `Fib` object returns `1`. If you call `advance` and then `getCurrentValue`, it returns `1` again, and after advancing a second time, it will return `2`. So it is not offset by one.